Minimum value of a function involving the divisor counting function
Fix any positive integer $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+,$ and consider the function $f_n : \mathbb{Z}^+\setminus\{n\}\to\mathbb{Z}^+$ given by $$f_n(t)=\sigma_0(n)+\sigma_0(t)-2\sigma_0(\gcd(n, t)),$$ where $\sigma_0$ is the divisor counting function. I am interested in the minimum value $$M=\min_{\mathbb{Z}^+\setminus\{n\}}f_n(t)$$ in the range of $f,$ and all $m\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ satisfying $f(m)=M.$ For example, $M=1$ if and only if $n=p^r$ (including $r=0$) is a power of a prime, and then $m\in\{p^{r+1}, p^{r-1}\}.$ In general, how can we find $M$ and the $m$-values?
Initially, I was working on a completely different problem which turned out to have this number theoretic interpretation. Other than this particular case I do not know anything worthwhile sharing here.

First note that if $t \not\mid n$, $f_n(\gcd(n, t)) < f_n(t)$.
We will split to cases:
If for the minimal $m$, $\gcd(m,n) \neq n$, we can assume $m \mid n$, otherwise $\gcd(n, m)$ would've been better. Then we have $\gcd(n, m) = m$, so $f_n(m) = \sigma_0(n) - \sigma_0(m)$. Now from $\sigma_0(p_1^{r_1} p_2^{r_2} \cdots p_k^{r_k}) = \prod (r_i + 1)$ it's obvious we want $m$ to be $n$ divided by one of its most common prime factors, and factorizing $n = p_1^{r_1} p_2^{r_2} \cdots p_i^{r_i}$ we get $\min_{m \mid n \\ m \neq n} f_n(m) = \frac{\prod(r_i + 1)}{\max r_i+1}$.
In the other case, $\gcd(m, n) = n$, so $n \mid m$. Now we want to minimize $\sigma_0(m) - \sigma_0(n)$. Again we use $\sigma_0(p_1^{r_1} p_2^{r_2} \cdots p_k^{r_k}) = \prod (r_i + 1)$, and now we want $m$ to be $n$ multiplied by one of its most common prime factor. We get the same value for $f_n(m)$, $\frac{\prod(r_i + 1)}{\max r_i+1}$.
Therefore, for $n = p_1^{r_1} p_2^{r_2} \cdots p_i^{r_i}$, $M = \frac{\prod(r_i + 1)}{\max r_i+1}$, and the values of $m$ which attain it are $n$ either divided or multiplied by one of the primes $p_i$ with maximal $r_i$.

No, if you divide by $p_i$ then $\sigma_0(m) = \frac{r_i}{r_i+1} \sigma_0(n)$ which is maximized for maximal $r_i$
